# New to structs for C, can someone help me define these structs?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

Im still very new to C but slowly learning and I know how basic structs work, but Im learning about these new ones. How exactly do I use them and how do they work memory wise?

Would greatly appreciate it

struct within a struct??

```
struct Multi {
   int which;
     union 
     {
       float f;
       double d;
       int i;
     } data;
};
```

struct pointing to itself?

```
typedef struct Other {
    double x;
    int* y[2];
    struct Other* z;
} Other;
```

this thing

```
typedef int const * (* const CallMe)(const int *);
```

more

```
typedef union {
    void (*theta)();
    void *(*iota)();
} Kappa;
```

Would greatly appreciate it.

If an example could be given like how to declare and initialize a single variable of that type, that would be great. I like working backkwards to try them out my self.

Comment: Smells like homework. Advise showing an attempt and/or asking a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

**First case (with the `union`)**

This is not exactly a struct within a struct. `data` is actually a union (if you're interested, see about unions [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_unions.htm)). If you're just learning structs, don't mind unions just yet - they aren't used all that often compared to structs, and you might get mixed up between the two.

This setup is quite classic in C. You have a field that tells you which of the field of the union you should use.

**Second case**

No, this is not a struct pointing to itself ; this means that a `struct Other` contains a pointer to a `struct Other`. So, you could have:

```
struct Other s1;
struct Other s2;
s2.z = &s1; // Now s2.z equals s1's address.
```

**Third case**

This has nothing to do with `struct`s. It's a [`typedef`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_typedef.htm) to the pointer of a function which takes a pointer to an `int`, and returns a pointer to an `int`.

**Fourth case**

Once again, this is not a struct, but rather a union. This union contains either (for `theta`) a pointer to a function with takes no argument and returns nothing, or (for `iota`) a pointer to a function which takes no argument and returns a void pointer.

Comment: Ahhh I apologize, i usually associated typedef with structs.